# async defer и data-turbolinks-eval в Django compresssor

Tags: python, django

Использую в проекте [django-compressor](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) и в процессе, возникло несколько вопросов.

1. [Здесь](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/blob/develop/compressor/js.py) я обнаружил, что если в исходном скрипте указан defer или async, то его нужно подтягивать в скомпилированный скрипт. В итоге получается так: `<script defer="" src="/static/CACHE/js/f4ea500c2678.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` или же `async=""` в случае указания async в исходном скрипте.

[Здесь](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp) же, да и везде, где бы я не читал, указано, что данный параметр нужно указывать без `=""`/

Я проверял код на валидность в [здесь](https://validator.w3.org/nu/), но как ошибка это не было отмечено, но мне кажется, что так работать не будет.

2. Я хочу указать параметр `data-turbolinks-eval="false"` в исходном скрипте, чтобы он подтянулся в компилированный, но встроенной возможности для этого нет.

Сейчас же, `data-turbolinks-eval="false"` не подтягивается.

Как сделать правильно?

Менять 2 строчки в исходнике, и отписать в github разработчиками? Или же я просто невнимательно прочёл документацию и пытаюсь усложнить себе жизнь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Что `async`, что `defer` - не важно, браузер сам добавляет этому атрибуту `=""`
2. Решение корявое и топорное, но работает:

в `env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/compressor/js.py`

сделал так:

```
elif 'defer' in attribs:
    extra = ' defer data-turbolinks-eval=false'
```

Понимаю, что в идеале бы получать дополнительные параметры из `settigs` и проверять их наличие на две строки ниже, и предложить принять это решение на [github](https://github.com/django-compressor), но отложу я это до лучших времён :)